# Sort array of subdocuments in mongodb with java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java

uI have an array of subdocument in the document of mongodb.
I want to sort those subdocuments.
I found it is possible to sort while updating the array.
link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/

I want to do this in java.
Here's part of my code:

```
BasicDBObject each = new BasicDBObject("$each", input);
BasicDBObject operations = each.append("$slice", "-10").append("$sort", new BasicDBObject("order",1));
push = new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("datas", operations));
collection.update(query,  push);
```

But it turns out that it didn't turn "operations" to operators but directly push them into documents and made "$each", "$slice" and "$sort" as fields.
Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented the java version of the query shown in the [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) you mentioned above.

Query is :

```
db.students.update( { name: "joe" },
                    { $push: { quizzes: { $each: [ { id: 3, score: 8 },
                                                   { id: 4, score: 7 },
                                                   { id: 5, score: 6 } ],
                                          $sort: { score: 1 },
                                          $slice: -5
                                        }
                             }
                    }
                  )
```

Using Java Driver you can implement it as follows :

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("students");

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name", "joe");

DBObject dbObj1 = new BasicDBObject();
dbObj1.put("id", 3);
dbObj1.put("score", 8);

DBObject dbObj2 = new BasicDBObject();
dbObj2.put("id", 4);
dbObj2.put("score", 7);

DBObject dbObj3 = new BasicDBObject();
dbObj3.put("id", 5);
dbObj3.put("score", 6);

BasicDBList eachList = new BasicDBList();
eachList.add(dbObj1);
eachList.add(dbObj2);
eachList.add(dbObj3);

BasicDBObject quizzesObj = new BasicDBObject();
quizzesObj.put("$each", eachList);
quizzesObj.put("$sort", new BasicDBObject("score", 1));
quizzesObj.put("$slice", -5);

coll.update(query, new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("quizzes", quizzesObj)));
```

Comment: Okay, I missed the BasicDBList part. Thanks!